# Can an InputMethodService or any backround service listen to other applications Input events like Keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I want to know whether the android system can notify if a keyboard is enabled in one app to other apps.

Answer (score 1):

This would be invasion of privacy. 
However, it can be done if you write an accessibility service
[onKeyEvent & Accessibility Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661861/onkeyevent-accessibility-service)

Comment: Thanks. I actually wrote my own Keyboard that helps me do what I want